# Unsolicited activity retry in Azure Functions orchestration

Tags: azure-functions, orchestration, azure-durable-functions

I have a long running (couple of minutes) job with an HTTP trigger implemented as Azure Functions orchestration:

```
[FunctionName("ManualImportOrders")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "POST")] HttpRequestMessage req,
    [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
    ILogger log)
{
    var dtoInResult = await ReadDtoInAsync(req);
    if (!dtoInResult.IsSuccess)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) { Content = new StringContent(dtoInResult.Error) };
    }

    string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("ManualImportOrders_Orchestrator", dtoInResult.Value);

    log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

    return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
}

[FunctionName("ManualImportOrders_Orchestrator")]
public async Task<object> RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var dtoIn = context.GetInput<ManualImportOrdersDtoIn>();

    var result = await context.CallActivityAsync<object>("ManualImportOrders_RunJob", dtoIn);

    return result;
}

[FunctionName("ManualImportOrders_RunJob")]
public async Task<object> RunManualAsync([ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext context, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var dtoIn = context.GetInput<ManualImportOrdersDtoIn>();
    logger.LogInformation("Invoking manual order import");
    var result = ... call to business logic ...
    logger.LogInformation("Manual order import completed");
    return result.Output;
}
```

There are three functions above:

- `ManualImportOrders` invokes the orchestration.
- `ManualImportOrders_Orchestrator` calls the single activity.
- `ManualImportOrders_RunJob` is the activity, that does the long running processing.

When the `ManualImportOrders_RunJob` activity function fails with an unhandled exception, I would expect that the whole orchestration fails. This happens when running locally with AF Tools indeed. But when run in Azure, it seems there is some retry mechanism, as the activity function is run again with the same instance ID.

For example, the first green run succeeded. In the second red run, the activity function failed and got recalled over and over:

[image: Functions log excerpt]

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: @FrankGong, yes, I will do that. Although it is only a workaround, currently it is a best solution. Strangely enough I cannot reproduce the issue with a new simple orchestration. There seems to be some other factor that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to find if there is a default retry mechanism for `durable function`, but I didn't find it, i am also very confused about this phenomenon.

But i think you can specify an automatic retry policy, this may reduce the number of calls to the activity function. The syntax for setting the retry strategy is this:

```
[FunctionName("TimerOrchestratorWithRetry")]
public static async Task Run([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var retryOptions = new RetryOptions(
        firstRetryInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        maxNumberOfAttempts: 3);

    await context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync("FlakyFunction", retryOptions, null);

    
}
```

You can set the value of `maxNumberOfAttempts` to the minimum. Hope this will help you.

For more details, you can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-error-handling?tabs=csharp#automatic-retry-on-failure).

Comment: Good idea, Frank. I will try maxNumberOfAttempts 1.